# SQL - rollup + date condition from different tables. how to connected these two queries into one?

Tags: mysql, rollup

Im creating database for a school project and i need to write code for a couple queries. i have an issue with the one that suppose to show total revenue for the specific period of time.in my case: total revenue=total sales-total refunds.
i have 4 tables: sales, sale_details, refunds, refund_details.
date details are in sales/refunds tables, everything else that i need is in sale/refund_details table.
Thats what i have so far:

## total sales

```
SELECT sale_id, sum(sale_price) as total_sales, sale_date
FROM sale_details JOIN sales USING (sale_id)
    WHERE sale_date > DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 28 day) 
    group by sale_id with rollup
```

## total refunds

```
select refund_id, sum(refund_price) as total_refunds, refund_date
FROM refund_details JOIN refunds USING (refund_id)
    WHERE refund_date > DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 28 day) 
    group by refund_id with rollup
```

Is there any way to combine those queries into one??? total sales minus total refunds

i was trying to complete the query in other way also(see below) but i dont know how to add the date or specific period of time to the query because date details are in separate tables in my database:

```
select(select sum(sale_price) from sale_details) as total_sale, 
(select sum(refund_price) from refund_details) as total_refund, 
(select sum(sale_price) from sale_details) - (select sum(refund_price) from refund_details) as total_revenue from dual;
```

i could move date details from those separate tables to the sales/refund_details tables but im not sure if it is a good solution so i would really appreciate your advice.My basic sql skills are useless here :/
thank you
Camille

PS. ERD diagram
[erd](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HNH4K.jpg)

Comment: How are `sale_id` and `refund_id` related such that you know which to subtract from which?

Comment: Hi Donnie, by product_id. ive just uploaded erd diagram